# UIImageView streches over entire row height of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

## Intro:

Hi, I'm working on a "News" app, that uses a news API online. I want to display the content of the latest news in a TableView (Currently I want to display the title of the news item, the name of the organization that posted it (e.g: the BBC), and an image that I load from a given link). I dragged a table view in the Main storyboard, created a custom cell for a singular news item, and get all of the required information from the internet.

## The Problem:

When all the data gets loaded into the TableView, the image streches across the whole rows height.

I'm trying to find a work-around for hours now. At the moment, In the prototype cell, I have a Stack View, that contains 2 labels and an ImageView, with a Vertical Axis, and a Distribution of Fill Equally.
There are no constraints on the Views inside the Stack View (the 2 labels and ImageView), and I'm not editing any constraints within the code, to keep it as simple as possible.
I also tried the constraints approach prior of using the stack view, but it gave the same result.

[Image Of The Stack View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q54tm.png)

[The Result in the Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnE99.png) (Rows without an image, don't have an image url provided by the api, so I just skip them).

I tried being as expressive as I can about the problem, if you are still missing some information please let me know

Comment: Is there any reason you have to use stack view? I think it is constraints issue

Comment: Don't use stack view. Use constraints

Comment: I'm using the stack view to simply things, I tried not using it, and simply using constraints between the items, but I got the same result.

Comment: try to set image height and width 10x10 constraints

Comment: Yeah, use constraints

Comment: Shouldn’t one avoid of using width and height constraints as it leads to non-dynamic layouts ?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can put priority to constraints and still can be manage to make scalable application. The problem with what you are doing is that app does not know how to place things without appropriate constraints. Try to use constraints and layout alignments

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are encountering is due to constraint issue. The problem should be solved by unstacking the view and put constraints instead.

You can still achieve scalable application using them.
If you are confused with how to do it, refer https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html

These should help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are in right Direction.

**if you want static(fixed) Layout Follow below step.**

1. change StackView Distribution from Fill equally to Fill
2. Apply StackView(leading,trailing,top,bottm) =
   cell(leading,trailing,top,bottm)
3. set tableView rowHeight to 300 or whatever you want

**if you want dynamic layout follow below step**

https://www.raywenderlich.com/1067-self-sizing-table-view-cells